# Clicking Add New button for custom taxonomy only moves element

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin, post-editor

When trying to click the "Add New Equipment Type" button for my custom taxonomy, it simply moves the DOM element up into the list of entries and fails to add the actual term.  Here is my taxonomy code:

```
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Equipment Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Equipment Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Equipment Types' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Equipment Types' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Equipment Type' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Equipment Type:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Equipment Type' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Equipment Type' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Equipment Type' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Equipment Type Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Equipment Type' ),
  );

  register_taxonomy('equipmenttype',array('powerequipment'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'power-equipment' ),
  ));
```

And this is what happens in the editor:

[image]

I'm not using any custom admin JavaScript and the only plugins I have enabled are Akismet and Wordpress Importer.  Also, this error does not occur with the standard Categories taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this exact problem, and it came down to a bizarre naming issue that I can't explain.

I have a post type `event` and I created a taxonomy `event_tag`. It exhibited the behavior you describe, as did any tax name beginning with `event`. Changing it to anything that didn't begin with `event` made it work again.

Comment: Sadly this is the exact same result I had.  Apparently having a taxonomy that begins with the same characters as a post type breaks the admin on the Edit Post screen.